# SSH terminal in browser

Tags: ruby, ssh, terminal

I want to implement ssh terminal client in web browser. I need to implement server for ssh connections in ruby. There is a net/ssh library, but i dont know how to handle fullscreen programs like vim or midnight commander.

Comment: And what exactly is your question?

Comment: Sorry for confusion. There is no exact question I want to ask, I just need to find direction for googling to implement my app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me attempt to reparse your questions: You're trying to emulate a SSH console session on the web browser. You appear to have implemented simple console input/output for most commands, but appear to be getting garbage appearing when you try out fullscreen commands like 'vim' or midnight commander.

The problem you're seeing is to related to how UN*X machines handle fullscreen console output on terminals. Fullscreen console applications consults the terminfo/termcap library to determine the escape-sequences required to clear the screen, delete a line, insert a line, put a cursor at a particular point, etc. What you're seeing is the raw output of these escape sequences appearing for the default terminal-type, which is most probably ANSI based.

To solve your problem, you have to:

1. determine the terminal type your console app emulating - or you can force it to something determinate.
2. decode the escape-sequences for the terminal-type by consulting termcap/terminfo database.
3. Implement the terminal-capabilities on your web browser app.

Depending on the tech-stack you're using to implement your browser-app, you may be able to find libraries that other people may have developed to solve this problem.

Comment: Thanks for reparsing my questions, keywords "terminfo" and "termcap" was the exact thing i was looking for :)